# The guests were witnessed (to have/having) a gala time

Tags: exam-questions

> The guests were witnessed (to have/having) a gala time, with most of them tapping their feet to the loud music.

Which is the correct form of *have* to be used here ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'To have' is best.  The phrase 'a gala time'  I don't recognise at all.  If (as it appears from the rest of your sentence) that the 'guests' were enjoying themselves there are more apt words to use. e.g. 'fun', 'great'...

The guests were witnessed (to have/having) a *fun* time,..

may be phrased as:

The guests were witnessed *to have* a *fun* time,...

provided that the commentary is being given in the past sense as suggested by your use of the word 'were'.  You could also write:

The guests were witnessed *to be having* a *fun* time, ...

wouldn't be incorrect, and would be a choice if writing literature.